# How to delete google app backends by using java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I read the Google App Engine backend docs, but I still can't understand how to stop backends  from java

Could someone give me a code example? how to delete the backends

Answer (score 0):

You can't. See here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/backends#Types_of_Backends

Dynamic backends are stopped automatically after about 15 minutes of inactivity.

Resident backends can only be stopped via `appcfg` or Admin Console.

Comment: thanks for the replay..but this done manuvally but i want to delete backends for last 2 months backends programatically by using java